# Can't start app on passenger wsgi

Tags: python, django, passenger

I try to run ancient application on django 1.3 and passsenger wsgi.

My passenger_wsgi.py is:

```
import sys, os
INTERP = sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'myvenv/bin/python')) 
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I get next error:

```
Raw process output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 320, in <module>
    app_module = load_app()
  File "/opt/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 61, in load_app
    return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
  File "passenger_wsgi.py", line 4, in <module>
    if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
  File "/home/gian/virtualenv/public__html_test_gian/2.7/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 314, in execl
    execv(file, args)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

EDITED:

I have changed INTERP variable on right `'/home/gian/public_html/test/gian/myvenv/bin/python'`

and now I get next:

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 320, in <module>
    app_module = load_app()
  File "/opt/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 61, in load_app
    return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
  File "passenger_wsgi.py", line 4, in <module>
    if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
  File "/home/gian/virtualenv/public__html_test_gian/2.7/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 314, in execl
    execv(file, args)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied'
```

Comment: Check the permission for "/home/gian/public_html/test/gian/myvenv/bin/python"

Comment: You should use `django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()` instead of directly using the `WSGIHandler` class.

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.append` return `None`, please give filepath to `INTERP` variable.

You might be have to use

```
INTERP = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'myvenv/bin/python')
sys.path.append(INTERP)
```

Comment: then I have ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi

Comment: for me its works `>>> import django.core.handlers.wsgi >>>` no error :(

Comment: check your django version, I have `django-admin --version
1.7.1`